# Solr http request api with password and PHP

Tags: php, tomcat, solr

I use the follwing security settings in `tomcat_installation\webapps\solr\WEB-INF\web.xml` to maintain security - username and password access - to Solr http request:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>Solr Lockdown</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
  <role-name>solr_admin</role-name>
  <role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>Solr</realm-name></login-config>
```

then in `tomcat_installation\conf\tomcat-users.xml` I set the role as:

```
<role rolename="solr_admin"/><user username="administ"  password="theStr0ngPass!"  roles="solr_admin"/>
```

I use PHP `file_get_contents()` to get a query such as:

`http://solr.mydomain.com/solr/wak/select?q=gaming&wt=json&indent=true`

However, applying the described above security settings will prompt -or need- a username and password!

**The question is:** how to supply them, the username and the password, in the request URL? Or how to modify the security settings of solr app on tomcat to accept them in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s as simple as this:
`http://username:password@solr.mydomain.com/solr/wak/select?q=gaming&wt=json&indent=true`

However, the usual caveats apply: Basic Auth is only Base64-encoded, and hence prone to MITM attacks, if sent over an insecure connection.

Comment: I guess because the `user:pass@host` pattern works almost anywhere, they simply thought it’s obvious that it can be used here, too.